# ¿Cómo imprimo el resultado de la función de agregación sum?

Tags: python, django

Tengo esto en mi encabezado:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
```

Y ésta es mi función:

```
def matriz_cxp(request, idProveedor=None):
    total = 0

    if idProveedor:
        form = Filtro_Proveedor_Form({'proveedor': idProveedor})
        lista_cxp = CuentaPagar.objects.filter(proveedor=idProveedor)
    else:
        form = Filtro_Proveedor_Form()
        lista_cxp = CuentaPagar.objects.all()

    total = lista_cxp.aggregate(Sum('subtotal'))
    print(total) # provisional

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Filtro_Proveedor_Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            idProveedor = request.POST.get("proveedor")
            return redirect("matriz_cxp", idProveedor)

    return render(request, 'matriz_cxp__salud.html', {
        'lista_cxp': lista_cxp,
        'total': total,
        'form': form,
    })
```

Pero ese `print` imprime esto:

```
{'subtotal__sum': 16000}
```

Y yo necesito ésto:

```
16000
```

¿Cómo modifico el llamado a la función?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función `aggregate` simplemente te agrega el campo como llave de un diccionario. Puedes intentar haciendo el `print` de esta manera:

```
print(total['subtotal__sum'])
```

Esto ocurre porque no le estás pasando el parámetro a la función y está tomando el nombre del campo pero es posible pasarle un nombre específico:

```
total = lista_cxp.aggregate(subtotal=Sum('subtotal'))
print(total['subtotal'])
```